# Alchemy - calling eth_getTransactionReceipt - HardhatError: HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received

Tags: javascript, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, alchemy

Please see my deploy.js.The code fails at line 23 with await fund.deployed();

```
const hre = require("hardhat")
const { fundConfig } = require("../helper.config");

async function main() {
    let usdcTokenAddress;
    if (hre.network.config.chainId == 31337) {
        // Deploying on localhost...
        // Deploy the Mock USDCStablecoin contract
        const usdcTokenContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("USDCStablecoin");
        usdcTokenContract = await usdcTokenContractFactory.deploy();
        await usdcTokenContract.deployed();
        console.log("MockUSDCStablecoin contract deployed to:", usdcTokenContract.address);
        usdcTokenAddress = usdcTokenContract.address;
    } else {
        // Retrieve USDC Address from Goerli
        const chainId = hre.network.config.chainId;
        usdcTokenAddress = fundConfig.network[chainId].usdcTokenAddress;
    }
    const Fund = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Fund");
    const fund = await Fund.deploy(usdcTokenAddress);

    await fund.deployed(); // <--- HERE

    console.log("Fund deployed to:", fund.address);

    // Verify the contract
    if (hre.network.config.chainId != 31337) {
        await fund.deployTransaction.wait(10);
        await hre.run("verify:verify", {
            address: fund.address,
            constructorArguments: [usdcTokenAddress]
        });
    }
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

This is the error I get.

```
HardhatError: HH110: Invalid JSON-RPC response received: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":18}
    at parseJsonResponse (.../contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/util/jsonrpc.ts:47:11)
    at HttpProvider._fetchJsonRpcResponse (.../contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:206:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at HttpProvider.request (.../contract/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:84:29)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (.../contract/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

I get this once I run `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli` , and yes `npx hardhat compile`, `npx hardhat test`, `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js` all works

The contract even got deployed https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xd72af54eaf53ec00d75f2a31d103ba8e1dce43541b679e3329c7ca34394ee154 (btw manually verified - as the script terminated with the error)

Then I created a new Alchemy project - I tried then on mumbai - also same error, but again it was still deployed. For a sanity check if the project setup in Alchemy was wrong.

Here are some screenshots from the Alchemy Dashboard...

You can see the transaction goes through

[image]

Here is the error inside the Alchemy Dashboard. Does not provide helpful information

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next day, I tried again and it worked. I didn't change a single line inside the deploy.js nor did I change environment variables, api-keys etc.

Must be a transient internal error.

If you encounter the same thing, please be patient and try later again.